# error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

I do not get Json from the server. Why is it possible?
What is err for what?

```
err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

api{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "ali",
        "Age": 25,
        "Img": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABMsAAATiCAYAAACkzmRcAAAABG..."

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<Employee> call = apiInterface.getUser();
 call.enqueue(new Callback<Employee>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<Employee> call, Response<Employee> response) {
         String res = response.toString();
         Log.d("response",res);
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<Employee> call, Throwable t) {
         String err = t.toString();
         Log.d("err",err );
     }
 });
```

Employee.java

```
 public class Employee {

    @SerializedName("Id")
    private int Id ;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String Name ;
    @SerializedName("Age")
    private String Age ;
    @SerializedName("Img")
    private String Img;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getImg() {............
```

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("get")
    Call<Employee> getUser();


}
```

ApiClient.java

```
 public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static final String BASE_URL = "??????????????????";

    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if ( retrofit == null ){

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You didn't paste the actual JSON text. JSON cannot start with `api{`. Also, the error says "was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2", which means that second character was a `[`, and there are no `[` in the JSON text you posted.

Comment: Thank you
I'm a beginner, you can get more tips

my api
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "ali",
        "Age": 25,
        "Img": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABMsAAATiCAYAAACkzmRcAAAA..."
    }

]

Comment: The `[]` means array (or list), so response is a `List<Employee>`, not just a single `Employee`.

Comment: tnx Andreas The answer was the same